# Is there a way to batch Disable / Enable all armature constraints to view a baked animation? Do I have to select and disable constraints one by one?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm experimenting with more detailed human character rigs with IK controls and since the animations are meant to be used in a game engine, I need to bake any animations made with IK constraints.

The issue is that after I bake an animation, all the constraints are still on the bones, affecting their movement so they end up compounding with the baked animation thus messing the preview so I can't view it unless I go though every bone that has a constraint and either disable or delete it manually. That or clear all constraints in the baking setting but that doesn't make sense because why should I destroy the constraints making it unusable for further animations.

So is there a way of batch disabling all constraints? Or perhaps a way of making it so that previewing baked animations automatically disabled constraints?

Someone had mentioned to make 2 armatures, one that has no constraints but is the main one to which the character mesh is attached and a second one that is a copy of the first armature but has all the constraints on it. Ultimately I'm supposed to use CTRL+L to link the animation data from the constraint armature to a non-constraint one. I can see this as an interesting solution but it also seems like a workaround to something that should just be a button for "disable/enable all constraints" no?

Comment: for sure this is possible via python...or maybe an add-on

Comment: I was looking for the same solution, but ended up just duplicating the armature like you suggested at the end.  Not ideal, but it does seem to work well enough

Comment: Screw it, I took a day off to make a plugin for this: https://github.com/TheConceptBoy/blender_bone_constraint_toggler

Apparently nobody thinks having two armatures is dumb.

Comment: This issue has been plaguing Blender for years, the developers have no concept of how important it is to occasionally disable the IK so as to pose the armature and see how the weight painting is deforming. I can't believe it's almost 2024 and Blender 3 and 4 still have not even tried to address the issue. IK being forced always on is a serious drawback to using Blender.

Comment: Maybe it's an industry standard? Because even rigify plugin contains two armatures with it's IKs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a plugin for just such an occasion.

It loops through all selected armatures, then loops through all the bones and disables or enables all the constraints within.

https://github.com/TheConceptBoy/blender_bone_constraint_toggler

Comment: Could you please write a full answer here that doesn't involve external links? External links can be lost, which might make your answer lose its value for this platform.